# Image uploader for TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, image, upload, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE in my webpage. Now I should save the images from my local system into the editor. I searched for plugins for this and all the available plugins are only in PHP. I am not aware of PHP and i am stuck with this issue. It would be really help full if anybody can post me a jquery or javascript plugin to do this.

I am using Java EE, tomcat server and do not know how to run PHP in this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ready-to-use plugin but here is a link for [how to implement a custom file browser](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser)

You can write your own server-side logic in any language